# syncing mysql database with Sqlite database in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to Sync `MySql` Database into `Sqlite` Database for Offline use also Insert Data which is Stored in Temporary into `Sqlite to Mysql`.

So I tried this Tutorial but not Helpful for me.

http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-remote-mysql-db-to-sqlite-on-android/

Give me a GitHub Link Or any Other tutorial which Is Easy  TO understand  Or implement.

Comment: The tutorial is quite clear, what do you miss ?

Comment: i done same as tutorial but project wont work properly i dont have knowlege about php or Json that the reason its hard to me for implementation... can u provide me another tutorial or github Project that will Help me ...

Comment: I can't provide you tuto, but, didi you tied to call you json service throught Postman ? I mean did you tried to call each item of your project without the others ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks For Help ..

Its all  Php Version Errors ..  i  was Tried mysql_connect on Newer version php 7

i make changes in php File. and also use depriciated Library for compile

'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

now its Working Fine..

Thanks Everyone.

Comment: you can use the room and work manager and sync the data by API but it's not a good idea best way to store the data offline in room db data and sync all data at once calling API every time it will increase the load on the server may be server get down and user will face performance issue